# What is the best CSS framework with Angular

Tags: css, angular, web, css-frameworks

Hi friends I am new to Angular , I currently using Angular 4 , I read and watching al ot of material about Angular i think it is so awesome , but I have big problem with the UI part of Anuglar , I used to using Bootstrap as CSS framework for the UI , but it require JQuery as a dependency I read from a lot of resources they said it is not good practice to using JQuery with Angular and also it will increase the size of application , and also I read about  Angular Material and Angular flex-Layout , but as i see there is more feature is missing comparing to Bootstrap or another CSS framework , my question is what is the best and stable CSS framework  which is not have any dependency to using with Angular

Comment: you can use `ng-bootstrap` which have all the features of bootstrap

Comment: but it is not stable and currently is beta version , i need stable version